# How to prevent to store also the 0 in decimal?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to save the `avg` of a value, that in this case corresponds to the average attendance of a venue, and for this, I created a new field called `avg` which has this structure: `decimal(10,3)`.

Now if I store a value like this: 2671, the field will contain: 2.671 that's correct, but if I need to store only `800` I'll get: `800.000` that's, of course, is a different number…

So how can I store the correct decimal value? In this case should be only 800, not 800.000.

Also, how can I adjust the bad values stored in the database without repeat all the insert?

Thanks.

Comment: 800 *is* 800.000.  What happens to 2671 to make it 2.671 ?

Comment: If you need to distinguish between "800" and "800.000" then you need to store the value as a string.  Arithmetically, the two values are equivalent.

Comment: @AlexK. so if I need to store `800.000` how can I see the difference against `800` and `800.000` that in the database are stored as `800.000` for 800 and `800.000` for 800.000?

Comment: The fractional part is zero so has no significance, 800 == 800.000 == true

Comment: What is the difference between `eight hundred` and `eight hundred point 000` ?  or you think 800.000 is `8 hundred thousand`?  If it bugs your for the display, just cut it using the functions of the language you implement it in.

Comment: @Nic3500 ok, I though that was a problem

Comment: I was asking since I know some languages use `800 000` (like French) and others use `800.000` (like English) to write hundred thousands.

Comment: @Nic3500 In English, "eight hundred thousand" would be `800,000`; in French, that would be `800.000`. The version with a space (`800 000`) is a compromise intended to retain the benefit of digit grouping without the ambiguity caused by locales using `,` and `.` the other way around.

Comment: @IMSoP: my banking site (in Quebec, so it supports both languages) uses `800.000` in English, `800 000` in French.  I had to open a ticket with then since they were forcing all users to use the `,` for cents.  If you entered `1.23 $` they would refuse the number and force you to put `1,23 $`.  But let`s not turn this into a language debate.

Comment: @Nic3500 Looking at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) I see I made one mistake, which is that French speakers would probably use a space for thousands (and a comma for decimals), so `1 234 567,89`. However, it backs up my previous understanding that the style used in the UK (where I live, so can talk about with some certainty) is also used in other English-speaking countries, including Canada, which is `1,234,567.89`. If your bank is really displaying "eight hundred thousand" as `800.000` in an English context, I'm pretty sure they're just plain wrong.

Comment: Okay, I understood what is the problem thank you guys

Comment: @Nic3500 That should be "35 000,00" and "35,000.00" in French and English respectively. Not sure where they got the idea to put "35.000,00" instead. That's like some very opinionated programmer inflicting their will on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal point is irrelevant, you can trim the decimal point using another function.